# Opening the project browser in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

From addin  Session.Repository.ShowBrowser is used to show the project browser but we have to provide tab name and url as argument for this.So what are the values for those arguments we can provide such that if project browser is not openend we want to open it from adddin

Answer (score 0):

Repository.ShowBrowser is used to call an internal browser and not the **project browser** .Its undocumented seems .

Please refer in [Sparx Community](http://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,4836.msg122273.html#msg122273) for more details .

Comment: In Ea  there are two dock windows created that project browser and the properties window but when my addin runs if the window is properties then how to switch back to project browser window through addin

Comment: I dont think  its possible through addin . Maybe some others would help you on this.

Answer (score 0):

As @dahsra said, this is not possible via API. You could mimic the key press `Alt-0` to enforce showing the project browser.

Comment: Since EA is an application we are not able to mimic key press through sendkeys.Because it can be done only for windows forms.